# Why asyncio throws CancelledError instantly on streams running on create_task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm testing with asyncio and streams trying to understand it and I've got an issue.

What I'm trying to do is open a connection to a server and create a coroutine for each stream, reader and writer, so I can interact independently with server. I can send and receive messages independently. This is because once the connection is open the server can send status messages to the client regardless it asks or not for it.

I'm trying to run input() on a Executor so it does not block the program.

The problem is that when I run the code the loop immediately finishes the coroutines, I don't get a chance to send nor receive something. The output is after the code.

```
import argparse
import asyncio
from asyncio import StreamReader, StreamWriter

async def msg_reader(reader: StreamReader):
    try:
        while data := await reader.readline():
            print(f"\r\n{data.decode()}\r\n> ")
        
        print(f"READER - Connection Ended\r\n")
    
    except asyncio.CancelledError as cerr:
        print(f"\r\nREADER ERR - {cerr}")
        print(f'\r\nREADER - Remote connection cancelled.')
    except asyncio.IncompleteReadError:
        print(f'\r\nREADER - Remote disconnected')
    finally:
        print(f'\r\nREADER - Remote closed')

async def async_input(prompt: str = "") -> str:
    ret_str = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, input, prompt)
    return ret_str

async def msg_writer(writer: StreamWriter):
    try:
        while True:
            msg = await async_input("> ")
            print(f"got: {msg}")
            
            writer.writelines([msg.encode()])
            await writer.drain()
    
    except asyncio.CancelledError as cerr:
        print(f"\r\nWRITER ERR - {cerr}")
        print(f'WRITER - Remote connection cancelled.')
    finally:
        print(f'WRITER - Remote closed')
        writer.close()

async def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "This is the client for the multi threaded socket server!")
    parser.add_argument('--host', metavar = 'host', type = str, nargs = '?', default = "127.0.0.1")
    parser.add_argument('--port', metavar = 'port', type = int, nargs = '?', default = 25000)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(f"Connecting to server: {args.host} on port: {args.port}")

    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(host=args.host, port=args.port)
    print(f'I am {writer.get_extra_info("sockname")}')

    asyncio.create_task(msg_reader(reader))
    asyncio.create_task(msg_writer(writer))

try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('\r\nBye!')
```

And the output is:

```
python3 btv_async_client.py
Connecting to server: 127.0.0.1 on port: 25000
I am ('127.0.0.1', 51990)
> 
READER ERR - 

READER - Remote connection cancelled.

READER - Remote closed

WRITER ERR - 
WRITER - Remote connection cancelled.
WRITER - Remote closed
```

Appreciate any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `main` function creates two background tasks and then just *returns*. When `main` returns, `asyncio.run` cleans up the event loop by (among other things) canceling all tasks. If you want `main` to run as long as `msg_reader` and `msg_writer` are active, you need to tell asyncio that, for example:

```
async def main():
    ... setup ...

    await asyncio.gather(msg_reader(reader), msg_writer(writer))
```

Comment: thanks. So I have to wait for it. This part worked fine. Now I'm having problem with StreamWriter. It only really sends data after I finish the script with ctrl + c. Coroutine msg_writer completes each while loop step but don't send data, Looks like it is just buffering and when I finish the execution then data goes. Would you know why this is happening?

Comment: @trebew I'd guess it doesn't fully drain for some reason, but it's hard to tell. That should probably be asked as a separate question, ideally with a minimal example to reproduce the issue.